# View not updating when splicing user from list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this problem in my app, when I use `slice` to remove  the user from the list. However, it does not remove from the list. I am getting the user with a API url call. But for some reason, it does not remove the user from the list. Please, have a look at my code. If, you guys want the full code, I have put it in my github. I hope we both can solve this. Thank you in advance.

> Here is my code:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter : {id: lawyerId}">

    <a class="back" href="#/lawyer">Back</a>

    <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
      Edit
    </button>

      <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>

    <a class="delete" ng-click="confirmClick(); confirmedAction(person);" confirm-click>Confirm</a>





    <div class="people-view">

      <h2 class="name">{{person.firstName}}</h2>

      <h2 class="name">{{person.lastName}}</h2>

      <span class="title">{{person.email}}</span>

      <span class="date">{{person.website}} </span>


    </div>

    <div class="list-view">

      <form>

        <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

          <legend>Basic Info</legend>

          <b>First Name:</b>

          <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName">
          <br>

          <b>Last Name:</b>

          <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
          <br>

          <b>Email:</b>

          <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">
          <br>


          <b>Website:</b>
          <input type="text" ng-model="person.website">
          <br>



        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> App.js

```
 var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);



  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {


    $scope.inactive = true;





        $scope.confirmedAction = function (lawyer) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.indexOf(lawyer);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
            $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
            $window.location.href = '#/lawyer';
        });
    };


});




app.directive('confirmClick', ['$q', 'dialogModal', function($q, dialogModal) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // ngClick won't wait for our modal confirmation window to resolve,
            // so we will grab the other values in the ngClick attribute, which
            // will continue after the modal resolves.
            // modify the confirmClick() action so we don't perform it again
            // looks for either confirmClick() or confirmClick('are you sure?')
            var ngClick = attrs.ngClick.replace('confirmClick()', 'true')
                .replace('confirmClick(', 'confirmClick(true,');

            // setup a confirmation action on the scope
            scope.confirmClick = function(msg) {
                // if the msg was set to true, then return it (this is a workaround to make our dialog work)
                if (msg===true) {
                    return true;
                }
                // msg can be passed directly to confirmClick('Are you sure you want to confirm?')
                // in ng-click
                // or through the confirm-click attribute on the
                // <a confirm-click="Are you sure you want to confirm?"></a>
                msg = msg || attrs.confirmClick || 'Are you sure you want to confirm?';
                // open a dialog modal, and then continue ngClick actions if it's confirmed
                dialogModal(msg).result.then(function() {
                    scope.$eval(ngClick);
                });
                // return false to stop the current ng-click flow and wait for our modal answer
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}])

/*
 Modal confirmation dialog window with the UI Bootstrap Modal service.
 This is a basic modal that can display a message with yes or no buttons.
 It returns a promise that is resolved or rejected based on yes/no clicks.
 The following settings can be passed:

 message         the message to pass to the modal body
 title           (optional) title for modal window
 okButton        text for YES button. set false to not include button
 cancelButton    text for NO button. ste false to not include button

 */
.service('dialogModal', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return function (message, title, okButton, cancelButton) {
        // setup default values for buttons
        // if a button value is set to false, then that button won't be included
        cancelButton = cancelButton===false ? false : (cancelButton || 'No');
        okButton = okButton ===false ? false : (okButton || 'Yes');

        // setup the Controller to watch the click
        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) {
            // add settings to scope
            angular.extend($scope, settings);
            // yes button clicked
            $scope.ok = function () {
               // alert("Lawyer is confirmed");
                $modalInstance.close(true);
            };
            // no button clicked
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };

        // open modal and return the instance (which will resolve the promise on ok/cancel clicks)
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<div class="dialog-modal"> \
              <div class="modal-header" ng-show="modalTitle"> \
                  <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h3> \
              </div> \
              <div class="modal-body">{{modalBody}}</div> \
              <div class="modal-footer"> \
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-show="okButton">{{okButton}}</button> \
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="cancelButton">{{cancelButton}}</button> \
              </div> \
          </div>',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                settings: function() {
                    return {
                        modalTitle: title,
                        modalBody: message,
                        okButton: okButton,
                        cancelButton: cancelButton
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        // return the modal instance
        return modalInstance;
    }
}])


  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/lawyer", {
    controller: "HomeController",
    templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
})
.when("/lawyer/:id", {
    controller: "LawyerController",
    templateUrl: "partials/about.html"
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/lawyer'

  });

});
```

Comment: @MarcusH check my github link, I have all my code in there

Comment: Yes I can see that. But if you supply us with a plunker where your code is running then it's easier for us to help you

Comment: can you just clone it, and run on your localhost and see it. Please. Because I already put it in github.

Comment: @MarcusH You still want me to put in a plunker or you are still trying to solve it?

Comment: Just left my computer so I'm not able to help u now. But i suggest u to create a plunker

Comment: @MarcusH Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/QWeD54vOmFLo8sTUIjAg?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't get the index from IndexOf when you using it on an array of objects like you do. Read more about the IndexOf [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control).

Instead, use map and then use IndexOf on that

Try it like this:

```
$scope.confirmedAction = function (lawyer) {
    var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(lawyer.id);
    $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1);
    console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
    $window.location.href = '#/lawyer';
};
```

And also, the controller changes will by default be detected by the digest loop of angular so no need to use `$scope.$apply`.
Also, simplifyed your plunker with the basic get array list and remove function. Use that to build your way forvered

https://plnkr.co/edit/w6NuVLcqzc5Rjs7L6Cox?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your answer. But, instead of using the mock.data in the services, can I use a api url remote ?

Comment: Np, the api url was not reachable from the plunker so thats why I added mocked data. You can use the api instead of the mock from your end ofcourse:-) just set the mock.use=false; @SuzyHakobyan

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan did you try my sugested solution?

Comment: Can you please show me a way, to do with a remote api url rather than a dummy json.?

Answer (score 1):

But the element is getting deleted from list right?

If yes then, Try this :

```
$scope.confirmedAction = function (lawyer) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.indexOf(lawyer);
      console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
      $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1);
      console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
      $window.location.href = '#/lawyer';
    });
});
```

Or

```
$scope.confirmedAction = function (lawyer) {
    $timeout(function () {
      var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.indexOf(lawyer);
      console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
      $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1);
      console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
 $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); 
      // $window.location.href = '#/lawyer';
    },1100);
});
```

Comment: you mean in the console, yes.

Comment: ok so, it does not remove the list once more. I tried the code with $timeout. I think is the href that reloads the page?

Comment: It deletes, with the second code. But I want the list to show again, without that user

Comment: And then I want when they reload the page, just dont bring the user showing again

Comment: $state is not defined... When I put:  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, $timeout, $state) it still gives an angular.js console error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146281/discussion-between-suzy-hakobyan-and-sangwin-gawande).

Comment: when I apply for the first code, in the console I get a error saying: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest`